# Stop Rails checking for params in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, parameters, nested

### The Application Concept:

I'm building a Ruby on Rails [3.2] application at the moment, which consists of 2 very basic controllers - `accounts` for the user authentication, and `messages` which belong to the accounts.

```
# app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

# app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accounts
end
```

I then, of coarse, setup my `routes.rb` to allow users to view their messages nested under accounts:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :accounts do
  resources :messages
end
```

### The Question:

I want users to access their accounts without using an ID parameter in the URL like this: `example.com/accounts/`, which works perfectly fine.

Whenever I try and go to: `example.com/accounts/messages` however, rails treats "messages" as a parameter for the `accounts_controller`! The only way I can access messages now is by going: `/accounts/5236/messages` - which is NOT what I want.

My question is, is there a way to block/mask rails from checking parameters on my accounts controller so that I can access my messages like the example above? I'm really puzzled on this one, so please share your thoughts and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add some closure to this question, I've decided to go with this solution in my `routes.rb` file:

```
get "/accounts/messages" => "messages#index", :as => :message
```

This works well, but the only downside is that it has to be manually added each time if you add controlers under the accounts namespace down the track. Oh well.

ForgetTheNorm also has a fantastic alternate solution below, so give that a shot if this doesn't work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Your defined routes

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :messages
end
```

implies you can only have URL like this :

```
/accounts/
/accounts/:id
/accounts/:id/:action
/accounts/:id/messages/
/accounts/:id/messages/:id
/accounts/:id/messages/:id/:action
```

If you want specify the URL `/accounts/messages/`, you must specify it in the routes

```
resources :accounts, :collection => { :messages => :get } do
  resource :messages
end
```

Comment: Hi there. Nope, sorry! It still seems to be taking me to the show action of accounts.

Comment: `get "/accounts/messages" => "messages#index", :as => :message` works, but surely there must be a more efficient way?

Comment: Update your first post and print a `rake routes` command (before and after putting the `:collection` I said), it will be helpful.

Comment: @AdamMcArthur Your `get` solution will work, and will be as efficient as any other. I just found my solution better for code clarity.

Comment: I'll just settle with that then. Thanks for your help :)